# Is this possible that Facebook will return an empty/null first name and last name?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Consider a situation when I call the `Facebook API` with user's `Access Token`.

There is one thing that I'm 100% sure I will get correctly: his `Facebook id` in a form `193248247238723592`.

I know that `email` can be `null` or empty, cause `Facebook` account can also be used with a phone number.

*But what about user's first and last names?*

Can I be 100% sure that I'll receive them? Are there any situations that user doesn't have his name set on Facebook, in some countries or something?